# use dropdown to show data from database in react, but it return undefined value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown, menuitem

The dropdown show the value from database, but when I select it the value is undefined.

```
import {
    Select,
    MenuItem,
    FormControl,
    InputLabel,
  } from "@material-ui/core"; 

function FilePush() {
const [categorias, setCategorias] = useState([]);
const [fileID, setFileID] = useState("");

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <Select onChange={(e) => setFileID(e.target.value)}>
        <MenuItem value="None">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>

        {categorias.map((categoria,index ) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>

            {categoria.json.map((f) => {
              return (
                <div key={f.filename}>

                   <MenuItem key={f.filename} value={f.filename} >{f.filename}</MenuItem>
                </div>
              );
            })}

            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      })}
         </Select>
        
         <p>You Selected: {fileID}</p>

    )
}
}

export default FilePush;
```

The code shows values that are coming from Database in the dropdown. However, when the options are selected, the result is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` within the `<Select>` element seems to be the problem.
In other words, the `<MenuItem>` needs to be placed directly below the `<Select>` element.

In your case, there are 2 `<div>` elements under `<Select>`.
Can you try removing it and see if it works?

I have confirmed the behavior with the below code sandbox.
Adding `<div>` create the issue and no `<div>` works fine.
(The code is forked from the MUI `<Select>` documentation.)
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sinoussi-4ow5ig?file=/demo.js

---

```js
{ 
  categorias.map((categoria) => {
    categoria.json.map((f) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem key={f.filename} value={f.filename} >{f.filename}</MenuItem>
      )
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the data from psql, and I need to loop the data twice. If I want to delete the div, then I have to delete the return. If I delete the return and div, I will have an empty dropdown.

Comment: @HaniMoghaddasi How about returning only `<MenuItem>`?
The sample code was added to the answer.

Comment: It makes the dropdown empty